# Printing error when using PARAMS in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

For my API in RAILS I have programmed a code that basically does the following.

```
class Api::V1::NameController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

    def index

    end

    def create
          # Loading data
            data_1_W = params[:data1]
            data_2_W = params[:data2]

       while len > i
          # -Here I do some calculations with data_1_W and data_2_W. 
          # Its not important to show the code here
       end

          # -Organizing outputs to obtain only one JSON-
          # Its not important to show the code here

          # Finally HTTP responses    
          if check_error == 1
            render status: 200, json: {
            message: "Succesful data calculation",
            data_output: response_hash
            }.to_json 
          end  

    end
end
```

To test that everything is working I use the cURL command. I notice that loading the data could be a problem and therefore the code would break.

I want to tell the user that it was an error loading the data for some reason (HTTP response), but I don't know where to put it. If I put and `else` under my success status it would not print it because the code breaks just starting (instead of sending the correct name `- d '@data.json'` of the data in cURL I send `-d '@dat.json'`).

The data I am loading is a JSON data `{"data1":[{"name1":"value1"},{"name2":number2}...],"data2":[{"name1":"value1"},{"name2":number2...}]}`. (This data has 70080 rows with 2 columns if we see it as a table, which I divided into two in my CODE for calculations purposes `data_1_W` and `data_2_W`)

Could anyone help me where to put it? more or less like this:

```
render status: 500, json: {
            message: "Error loading the data",
            }.to_json
```

Comment: Its pointless to render a 500 whenever you know what is rescued, a 422 is just fine

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a rescue block around the code that throws the error.

E.g.

```
def func
  # code that raises exception
rescue SomeException => e
   # render 422 
end
```

Comment: its not a good idea to rescue everything, namely `Exception`. Its pointless to render a 500 whenever you know what is rescued, a 422 is just fine

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working in Rails I'd recommend going the rails way. This means that I would create some kind of service and initialize it in the create action.

Now, within the service you do all you funky stuff (which also allows you to clean this controller and make i look prettier) and the moment a condition is not fulfilled in that service return false. So...

```
# controllers/api/v1/name_controller.rb
...
def create
   meaningful_variable_name = YourFunkyService.new(args)
   if meaningful_variable_name.perform # since you are in create then I assume you're creating some kind of resource
      #do something
   else
      render json: {
        error: "Your error",
        status: error_code, # I don't think you want to return 500. Since you're the one handling it
      }
   end
end

# services/api/v1/your_funky_service.rb
class Api::V1::YourFunkyService
   def initiliaze(params)
     @params = params
   end

   def perfom #call it save if you wish
      ....
      return false if check_error == 1 
   end
end
```

Comment: this opens the door to another debate, what a good service should return? http://slides.com/apneadiving/service-objects-waterfall-rails#/

Comment: Absolutely agree. The service thing was an extra I added cause I saw all the logic clottering inside the controller. The returning value should be adjusted to what fits better your necessities (in my humble opinion). I use false cause in that way my controller keeps the 
if something
 #blah
else
 #bluh
end
format

Comment: I agree, but false doesnt provide the reason. I develop my theory in the slides

Comment: Well, since in your service you'll probably interact with a model, the errors on the instance (which is not valid for saving) could be returned. And if there's no instance just a condition failing the return your custom error

Comment: problem is to have a standard way to code your services, and services dont necessarily rely on an instance you pass to them. And what about chaining etc...

Comment: May I ask what is in this case args? Im just trying to understand the code. That means I have to make the request with cURL with the URL: YourFunkyService instead of name_controller?

Comment: args is just a name I gave to the parameters you pass into the service. In your case is data1 & data2 - You decide how to build the service ergo how to initialize it...it's just another class. Your request stays as it was. Our talk here was about the proper returning value form the service. Just don't return 500